# Repeat command in Aquamacs

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

I am running ESS on Aquamacs.

When I execute a command in the command line I can press esc-p to repeat the line.
However, when I execute a command from another buffer and then go to the command line, esc-p only repeats the commands that were typed in the command line.

Is there a way to repeat the commands that were executed from another buffer?